# Strange issue with YouTube user agent being stuck

Tags: youtube, safari, cookies

Every time I login to YouTube, webpage switched to mobile layout with related video below player with description and comments on the right side. Page seems to expect finger touches making it harder to highlight text.

Issue is happening in Safari 17.4 but it was happening through last few OS updates. I tried to delete cookies and cache for all YT and Google related domains but issue persists. I tried to change user agent but it seems to have no effect. Before their last aggressive push with advertisement changing user agent worked fine but not anymore. At one point I had to force YT into mobile view because advertisement was successfully blocked that way.

Extensions I have installed does not seem to affect the situation in any way. If I visit YT in Safari Private Window page loads in desktop mode as expected like it does in Firefox or Brave. If I load YT in Safari without Private Window without being signed in, it loads in desktop mode as expected. As soon as I sign in YT it switches to mobile version and I'm unable to change it. It only happens if I'm signed in.

I'm stuck, does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with the user profile. Does it happen with another YT login?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting-like questions are off-topic in Web Applications Stack Exchange.